# Signed android apk crashes but debug does not

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, code-signing, android-install-apk

I have an apk that runs perfectly fine on emulator and on real devices, however this is an unsigned APK. When releasing to the android store you need a signed apk, I have tried in eclipse doing:

```
Project->Android Tools->Export Signed Application Pacakge
```

Then I go through the whole wizard create my keystore and everything else and get a signed APK when it is done, however this APK crashes on startup on all devices I have tested. Normally I would look in the console and see what is breaking / not working but when you go through the eclipse wizard the console does not change.

Is there a different way to do this? what could be happening in the signing process that causes it to crash on startup? Thanks for any info.

**Edit**

I found the answer to my issue so if anyone else has this problem this is what worked for me. I was using ANT to build my APK, if you go to Project->android Tools->Export Signed package etc it does NOT use ant, any program did not work, to fix this drag the build.xml icon to the top right ANT corner, this brings up a list of ANT functions, then run BUILD apk rather then DEBUG APK (the default) after this you get an unsigned apk, you can then sign it and align it and it works great@!

Comment: do you maybe use porguard only in release version? Pls post your build script

Comment: "Pls post your build script"

Comment: Use adb logcat on the command line to get the stack trace.

Comment: 1. Post a stack trace from logcat, that;s the only way for anyone (including yourself) to see what the error is. 2. The difference between a debug apk and a signed apk is only the certificate used to sign it. Is there anything in your app (or anything that your app uses) that depends on being signed by a particular certificate? Perhaps some external APIs for which you registered for a key based on your certificate?

Comment: Ummm... where is build.xml? I am using Eclipse for Mac

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me a lot in Eclipse when i had many different libraries and dependencies in my project.

Try to disable Project/**Build Automatically** before you are exporting your apk.

[image]

NB: dont forget to turn Build automatically back on after the export.